# 'Tag-removed' tags where they possibly shouldn't be

Tags: discussion, tags

See

- [Why is differentiating mechanics and integration art?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66377)
- [Which functions of one variable are derivatives ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66462)

both of which are tagged [tag-removed]. Also, both of these seem to have had these tags from the beginning, though I suspect it is due to some script or other, or some merging of tags (e.g. [calculus])

Should we be somehow cleaning up questions tagged like this? There's [418 such questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed), but some of them probably *should* have [tag-removed], and some of them shouldn't. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Just to make clear what the appropriate process for dealing with [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed)...

> **Whenever you see such a question on the front page, do not hesitate to remove the tag!**

Since this tag mostly occurs as the result of an inappropriate tag being purged from the system, associated questions are often (but not always!) rather poor and destined to automatic deletion after some time. If you feel the urge to cleanup some questions with this tag, it is recommended that you start with the oldest ones (last page of the [newest list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed?sort=newest)) since you will find a higher density of good questions there.

Comment: Could I suggest not doing this for the really old ones if they have an accepted answer? Instead I would prefer to go through ones which are open, either with no answers, or with no answers that are satisfactory

Answer (score 1):

The usage of [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed) was two-fold:

- as an 'empty' tag for massively off-topic and mistagged questions.
- as a tool to 'delete' tags via merging them into it.

Due to the second use-case numerous legitimate questions also got this tag. I think it could make sense to go over this list and retag some of the question. Mainly, those that are legitimate question that are meanwhile very badly tagged, e.g., only with [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed)

Due to the first case there might also be some very poor questions in this tag (I did not check this is a guess, based on the usage and a remark in OP). For those one might consider deletion or just leaving them poorly tagged.

It could also now be a good time to start this, since (at least in principle, I do not know if for their work-flow the moderators still use it or want to use it) this tag for the second use-case is not necessary anymore on SE2.0. The dedicated tag serving this purpose is [untagged](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: I know, quid - I was one of the people who did a bit of the first case a little too enthusiastically at first. There are definitely some poor questions there, but the two examples I gave are actually very interesting questions with good answers, so I guess there are others.

Comment: I did not mean the two question you linked to with the poor questions, but I meant your remark that some should have this tag, which can basically only be true for a poor question, else there ought to be some better tag and if not one should create one. Also, I assumed you were aware of the two use-cases, but since I wrote an answer I thought I recall it for those that might not. But in view of the untagged thing now present I really think this could be a good moment to start the clean-up. (Personally I will not help much, since I have a long list of other retags I want to do.)

Comment: ok, I understand you now.

Comment: Good. I have to admit I was not very clear. A point I think I blurred in my answer a bit too much is that I think regarding this clean-up in my mind one should not consider the tag-removed as something that should be removed from good questions as an end in itself (as it makes them somehow 'look bad'). But rather that (at least the first) goal should be to get those good question that are poorly tagged at the moment properly tagged (the most extreme scenario being only tag-removed, but there are some, meanwhile I looked a bit, with it and a very general one.