# Tags for off-topic question

Tags: discussion, tags, minor-edits

This is a pretty minor issue, but what should I do (if anything) when there are no appropriate tags for an off-topic question, e.g. [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348520/is-there-a-program-that-i-can-use-for-very-large-numbers-over-10206-without)?

I tried to delete the existing tags but can't without supplying a substitute.  My inclination was to create a new tag, **off-topic**, but it occurs to me that if this were a good idea, we'd already have that tag.

Of course the question is closed and will disappear in due time so maybe no action is called for.

Comment: If the question, though off-topic for MO, is still mathematics, maybe the general-mathematics tag would do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a special [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed) option for clearly off-topic cases like this.

Comment: Here is a link to the post where some more details about ([tag:tag-removed]) can be found: ['Tag-removed' tags where they possibly shouldn't be](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/657). (It is also linked [in the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/tag-removed/info).)

Comment: The fact that many deleted questions have this tag suggests that it's indeed used in this way. [Recently deleted questions with this tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1170442/recently-deleted-questions-in-a-specific-tag?tagname=tag-removed). (10k+ users can also see the actual questions from the links.) The tag (tag-removed) has [highest percentage of deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1162648/percentage-of-deleted-question-per-tag?num=1000) (as mentioned [recently in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2019/12/6)).